# Python table error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I always get this error for this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/ankosh/trial13.py", line 14, in <module>
    if grades_mix[index_no]=="HM1":
IndexError: list index out of range)
```

I would really appreciate the help.

```
  `file_pointer=open("C:/python27/Doc/student_grades.txt", "r")

   read_grades=file_pointer.readline()

   my_list=[]

   while 0==0:

    grades_mix=read_grades.split()

    name_str=grades_mix[0]

    contained_list=[name_str,0,0,0,0,0.0]

    index_no=1

    count_num=0

sum_float=0.0

avg_float=0.0

while 0==0:

         if grades_mix[index_no]=="HM1":

           index_no+=1

           grade_num=int(grades_mix[index_no])
        count_num+=1
        sum_float+=grade_num
        contained_list[1]=grade_num
    elif grades_mix[index_no]=="HM2":
        index_no+=1
        grade_num=int(grades_mix[index_no])
        count_num+=1
        sum_float+=grade_num
        contained_list[2]=grade_num
    elif grades_mix[index_no]=="HM3":
        index_no+=1
        grade_num=int(grades_mix[index_no])
        count_num+=1
        sum_float+=grade_num
        contained_list[3]=grade_num
    elif grades_mix[index_no]=="HM4":
        index_no+=1
        grade_num=int(grades_mix[index_no])
        count_num+=1
        sum_float+=grade_num
        contained_list[4]=grade_num

    index_no+=1
if count_num>0:
    avg_float=sum_float/count_num
contained_list[5]=avg_float
index_num=0
while index_num<len(my_list):
    if my_list[0]>name_str:
        break
    index_no+=1
my_list.insert(index_num, contained_list)
read_grades=file_pointer.readline()
   file_pointer.close()

   print format ("Name","<10")+" | "+format("HM1"," >5")+" | "+format("HM2"," >5")+" | "+format("HM3"," >5")+" | "+format("HM4"," >5")+" | "+format("avg_float"," <10")+" | "

   for index_no in range(0, len(my_list)):

    print format(my_list[index_num][0], "<10") + " | " + \

       format(my_list[index_num][1], " >5") + " | " + \

       format(my_list[index_num][2], " >5") + " | " + \

       format(my_list[index_num][3], " >5") +  " | " + \

       format(my_list[index_num][4], " >5") + " | " + \

       format(my_list[index_num][5], " >10.2f") + " | "
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code to a minimal example demonstrating the problem? Also please check the indentation, it looks broken. You can [edit] the question to fix this.

Comment: You don't want to write 0==0 when you can just write `True` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have, in abbreviated form:

```
while 0==0:
   if grades_mix[index_no]=="HM1":
      index_no+=1
```

with no break statement to ever get out of the loop (which, how about `while True`?).  Sooner or later you're going to go out of range.

Comment: but someone else has basically the same code without any break statement and it works just fine ?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is in that word 'basically'.  Without seeing the other code, I can't help you.  If you have an array like `lst=['a', 'b', 'c']` and you try to get `lst[4]`, you'll get the error you got.  Try changing the `while 0==0` to `while index_no < len(grades_mix)`

Answer (score 1):

The error message

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

indicates that you are using an index that does not exist in the array. Try to check the size of the array by printing out its length

print "length of array grades_mix =" ,len(grades_mix)

If the length of the array is less than or equal to 1, then you will get an error at the first step when calling

```
grades_mix[index_no]
```

with

```
index_no=1
```

It might be that your file contains empty lines or lines with a single word, you need to take care of that in your script.

Comment: i printed the length of the array grades ,
it printed out 7

Comment: Well then the error occurs 6 steps later in your (infinite) loop, you need to stop the loop before it reaches that point